# Does there exist a unitary matrix such that $Uv=\|v\|e_{1}$ for $v\in\Bbb{C}^{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, unitary-matrices, tridiagonal-matrices

Let $v\in\Bbb{C}^{n}$ be a fixed vector. Then does there exist a unitary Matrix $U$ such that $Uv=\|v\|e_{1}$? or even $Uv=c\|v\|e_{1}$ for some real constant $c$?

I am looking for a Householder reflection sort of a transformation.

For example, if $v\in\Bbb{R}^{n}$ or even if $\langle v,e_{1}\rangle\in\Bbb{R}$, then the standard Householder reflection $H=I-2uu^{*}$ where $u=\frac{v-\|v\|e_{1}}{\|v-\|v\|e_{1}\|}$ would suffice. But this won't work for general $v\in\Bbb{C}^{n}$.

Comment: @Justauser $v$ is a fixed vector. I am not asking for all $v$. As I said, if say $v\in\Bbb{R}^{n}$. Then the matrix I provided works.

Comment: @Justauser From the context, $v$ seems fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $v=0$, any unitary matrix works.
Let's then assume $v \neq 0$, and let $f_1 = v/\|v\|$, and complete it into an Hermitian basis $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$.
Consider the $\Bbb C$-linear map $u\colon \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C^n$ defined by its action on the basis $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ as $u(f_i) = e_i$, with $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ the canonical basis.
Then $u$ is unitary: indeed, if $x = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_if_i$, then
$$
\|u(x)\|^2 = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i e_i\right\|^2 = \sum_{i=0}^n|\lambda_i|^2 = \left\|\sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i f_i\right\|^2 = \|x\|^2.
$$
This should solve your problem.

Comment: What's an Hermitian basis? I am afraid that's the first time I am hearing it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: It's an orthonormal basis for the Hermitian inner product. That's just the generalization of usual real orthonormal bases but for $\Bbb C$-linear spaces

Comment: Ah I see. The term was unfamiliar to me. Please give me some time to digest your answer after which I'll upvote and mark also . Thanks .